# What's the best way to use Doctrine1 and Doctrine2 simultaneously in a Symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

We're considering migrating a big project we actively mantain from symfony1.4 to Symfony2.

This application is heavily tested functionally with Selenium (Unit tests are almost non-existing - Doctrine1/symfony1 didn't invited us much to do those), and we want to progressively reimplement our features in Symfony2 in a transparent way so that we can keep running those functional tests to validate that we're not breaking anything in the process.

We have been searching for articles of people who might have gone the same path before for ideas on the best approaches, but one part that we do not see any recommendation or feedback wether it's easy, possible and how could we do progressive reimplementations of our Model layer, in specific.

**My question is, has anyone ever used, inside a Symfony2 project, Doctrine1 in parallel with Doctrine2? In what ways can we achieve that and what problems should we expect?**

---

For added context, below is how we figure we can handle all the other issues of progressive reimplementation of an app from symfony1.4 to Symfony2.

For the **Controller**, we can use the approach described by Stefan Koopmanschap [here](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2011/12/painless-well-less-painful-migration-to-symfony2/) and the associated Bundle to have unimplemented routes fallback transparently to a symfony1 project. Maurits van der Schee also [improved over it](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2012/02/migration-to-symfony2-continued/), with a good approach on how to share auth and security between both apps.

For the **Views**, we expect to be able to use a symbolic link to share the "web/" assets between projects and we would start copying them from sf1 to Sf2 and use [php](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) as a temporary template engine.

For the **Model**, we can have Doctrine2 generate boilerplate from the original sf1 database, but the process to reimplement all the business logic in the Model in Doctrine1 Classes into Doctrine2 Classes is expected to be arduous, so we would much prefer to do it in a progressive way, having sometimes Sf2 use Doctrine1 code (if not yet reimplemented) and use the equivalent Doctrine2 (if already reimplemented). 
We don't absolutely need this to be automatic (that would be great, but not sure if it's feasible), the Controller or other Model classes could be the ones to decide wether to use Doctrine1 or Doctrine2 in each situation. Is this a achievable? How, exactly? What are we forgetting? What is complex and what is easy?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this situation with Symfony 1.4 and Symfony2. Symfony 1.4 and Symfony2 -- and Doctrine 1 & 2 -- just will not work together.

Our solution was to create plugins in Symfony 1.4 that access a separate web app -- a new Symfony2 web app that would eventually replace the Symfony 1.4 web app.

Create an API in Symfony2 that exposes data from the same database that the Symfony 1.4 app accesses.

For example, let's say your Symfony 1.4 app has these routes:

- `/home`
- `/orders`
- `/sales`

In your Symfony 1.4 app, remove the controller and routes for `/sales`. Your goal is to move the `/sales` route to Symfony2. You want to do this modularly -- replacing one piece (each route) at a time.

Create a Symfony 1.4 plugin that accesses the new app you've created in Symfony2 -- the Symfony2 app  handles the `/sales` route now. Symfony 1.4 gets it's information now from the Symfony2 API you have created.

/home and /orders still exist in Symfony1.4, but you've moved /sales to Symfony2.

Piece by piece, add functionality to the Symfony2 app. Remove the routes from Symfony 1.4 as you go.

I hope this helps. I'm not sure I explained it very well. I'm happy to answer any questions.